# Xamarin app crashes suddenly while using a poor connection

Tags: c#, xamarin, crash, crash-reports

When my app suffers connection issues, it crashes suddenly and  throws no exceptions. I have putted microsoft app center plugin and this is the crash report:

```
Xamarin Exception Stack:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Project.XAML.AtendimentosUser.GetData (System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection data) [0x000f3] in <8ee15104665a463180bbffb742ed9570>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <0db975f2d36842718f4da4da36d2fcb7>:0
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <c2957c7ec1ac46f688b7f30f24232572>:0
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <c2957c7ec1ac46f688b7f30f24232572>:0
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <c2957c7ec1ac46f688b7f30f24232572>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.35(intptr,intptr)
```

Code of method AtendimentosUser.GetData:

```
async void GetData(NameValueCollection data)
{
    /* try {  */
    
        StackListagem.IsVisible = false;
        SemResultados.IsVisible = false;
        LoadingItems.IsRunning = true;
        LoadingContainer.IsVisible = true;

        WebService client = new WebService();
        agendamentos = await Task.Run(() => client.PostData<List<Agendamento>>(url, data, debug: true));

        LoadingContainer.IsVisible = false;
        LoadingItems.IsRunning = false;

        if (agendamentos.Count > 0)
        {
            LabelListagem.Text = "Você tem " + agendamentos.Count + " agendamento(s) para " + ((Mes)PickerMes.SelectedItem).label + " de " + PickerAno.SelectedItem;
            ListagemAgendamento.ItemsSource = agendamentos;
            StackListagem.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CaptionTxt.Text = "Você não possui agendamentos" + Environment.NewLine + " para " + ((Mes)PickerMes.SelectedItem).label + " de " + PickerAno.SelectedItem;
            SemResultados.IsVisible = true;
        }
    
    /* } catch  { GetData(data); } */
}
```

I just added the try/catch but I don't know if this will correctly handle the problem.

Do you guys see what can be causing this issue?

Comment: you need to null check `agendamentos`

Comment: oh.. you mean something like  if (agendamentos!=null && agendamentos.Count > 0) ??

Comment: your try/catch will not work with `PostData` since that is being run in a task - it needs its own try/catch block

Comment: yes, or `if (agendamentos?.Count > 0)`